# How to use jQuery to retrieve ONLY the second item in a comma-separated value on a hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these input fields:

```
<input class="things" type="hidden" value="FirstItem,SecondItem"/>
<input class="things" type="hidden" value="FirstItem,SecondItem"/>
```

How do I retrieve only the second values? Do I have to use an array that skips the first value? I tried something like this but it doesn't seem to work as I'm not being specific enough:

```
querySelectorAll('.things').val().split(",");
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Are there supposed to be two inputs?  If so, do you want the value from both?

Comment: If you want to access just the second hidden input you might try something like: `$('.things').last().val()` But your question does not state very clearly what your problem is.

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` will throw an error, given that it returns a collection, not a single node; and `val()` is not native JavaScript.

Comment: It looks like you have mixed jQuery and native JS. My guess is that you are looking for `$('.things').each(function(el) { alert(el.val().split(',')[1]); });`

Comment: The second part of the questing with splitting is already answered, but is it just me, or it is quite strange to not have a `name` property specified? It could help to select it by referring to it as `.things[name=xyz]`.

Answer (score 4):

So in order to do this with one or more hidden input fields, I am leveraging jQuery (personal preference).

1. First, I loop through the given hidden input fields. To do this you need the correct selector from which I use `$("input[type=hidden].things")`. You could just use `$(".things")` or `$("input[type=hidden])`, but combining the two makes for a more specific selector to your question as you ensure that hidden input fields are being used as well as those with the `.things` class.
2. Second is extracting the value (I used `alert()` for testing purposes only). By using `split(",")` you separate the strings within the current - `$(this)` - input field by comma. This produces an array of two elements (in our case). You want the second value in the array which is referenced by **[ 1 ]**.
3. So what do I do now? You can store `$(this).val().split(',')[1]` in a variable and use it to your own desire, you can pass it to a function or have it as a returned value from an anonymous function. The implementation is now up to you, good luck!

*JQuery code:*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type=hidden].things").each(function(key, value){
    alert($(this).val().split(',')[1]);
  });
});
```

Further reading references: **[split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)**, **[each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)**, **[val](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**, **[jquery attribute selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)**.

Comment: This answer works only for some interpretations of the question.

Comment: @DavidThomas I just added the explanation, I wanted to take my time with it :)

Comment: Shouldn't you check for a comma first?

Comment: @ragerory truth be told a lot more checking can be done (and I would), but its entirely dependent on the specifics of the problem that are outside the scope of the question, which means its better not to elaborate unless so the OP requests themselves

Comment: @AGE Agreed. Might be helpful to note it will throw an error if no comma is found, though. But you have references to the documentation, lead a horse to water, as they say.

Comment: @jonas.koeritz I corrected my selector to be much more specific to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
        var secondValues = $(".things").map(function(elm){
            return this.value.split(',')[1];
        }).get().join();
```